# How can i prevent click on a html element before completion of animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I am expanding/collapsing a div using a click event bind on the div.
The expand/collapse takes place using 
`$('#myid').animate(myfunctiontocollapse/expand)`.
Now for instance height of div is zero and i click on div to expand it and i click it again before completion of its expansion,the code for collapse is called and div gets out of shape.
How can i prevent click event for the second time when collapse/expansion is going on?

Comment: You can use `.stop(true)` and you can unbind the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if it's still animating in the click function and if it is then return false to prevent default click action and propagation.

```
if($('#myid').is(':animated')){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unbind the click and then rebind the handler as part of the completion parameter

It's not clear what your animation function is, but `show()` might be a better option for you:

```
var myClickHandler = function(el){
    $(el).unbind("click");
    $('#myid').show('slow', function() { $("#mytrigger").click(myClickHandler) }
}
$('#mytrigger').click(myClickHandler);
```

You can do the same with `animate()` as well if your function really is that custom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.stop()`  http://api.jquery.com/stop/ method to stop the currently running animation.

Here is a sample code.

```
$('#hoverme-stop-2').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('img').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('img').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: i am not trying to stop animation.i am trying to stop the click event if fired for the second time.